# Javascript - Nothing happens when I click this button connected to a function

Tags: javascript, html

So, I'm trying to validate an input field, where an input field cannot be empty. If someone doesn't enter any text into the input field and click 'start a new game' button it should display an alert message saying you need to enter a name.

However, my code does not display the alert message for some reason.
Here's my code.

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title>Tic Tac Toe</title>
</head>
<script>
  function myFunction() {
    if (document.getElementById(“playerNameNew").innerHTML == null) {
      alert("Name must be filled out");
      return false;
    }
  }
</script>

<body>
  <header>
    <h1>Tic - Tac - Toe</h1>
  </header>
  <h3>Start a new Game</h3>
  <input type="text" id="playerNameNew" placeholder="Enter your name" required>
  <button onclick="myFunction()" id="new">Start a New Game</button>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Are there any error messages in the Javascript console?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Three issues:

- `getElementById` is an object, however, what you really want is to call that function as follow `getElementById(...)`.
- `.innerHTML` returns the HTML rather than the entered value.
- You have to compare against an empty value rather than null (Use the function `.trim()`).

**Recommendation:** Use the function `.addEventListener()` to bind the click event.

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title>Tic Tac Toe</title>
</head>
<script>
  function myFunction() {
    if (!document.getElementById("playerNameNew").value.trim()) {
      alert("Name must be filled out");
      return false;
    }
  }
</script>

<body>
  <header>
    <h1>Tic - Tac - Toe</h1>
  </header>
  <h3>Start a new Game</h3>
  <input type="text" id="playerNameNew" placeholder="Enter your name" required>
  <button onclick="myFunction()" id="new">Start a New Game</button>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Deleted my answer in lieu of this one. Just to expand on the first listed issue, `.getElementById` is a method being called on the `document` object, meaning it gets parentheses rather than square brackets. You could also omit the `== ''` entirely and pad the front of the if statement with `if (!document. . .` so it will always check for a truthy value.

Answer (score -1):

```
  if (document.getElementById("playerNameNew").value == '') {
    alert("Name must be filled out");
    return false;
  }
```

Comment: the anwer should explain what was wrong in the original code and how you fixed it.